# How to open camera in the same view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am creating an application in which i need that in one page there is a button and one view.
When i click on that button i want to open camera in that view only not separate view of camera. Is it possible? 
And if yes, please provide me some hint or code.
Thank you.

Comment: If you read the documentation for UIImagePickerController you will get the answer.

Comment: what's wrong with opening camera in another view controller, whether you can pass your delegate, and use it as in your own view, ammm.. may be you want to open camera in small area(in same view), If I am right the you can find your solution in this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/7319927/656600

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible in iOS 4+ using the [AVCaptureSession framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
 like:

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
previewLayer.frame = aFrame; 
[self.yourView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
```

You can find more help [here](http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/).

Comment: It is for video recording. Isn't it??

Comment: You can capture still images with AV Foundation, not just video. See [AVCaptureStillImageOutput](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureStillImageOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVCaptureStillImageOutput).