# How to create a custom UIImagePickController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

In my application i would like to create custom application like this FDJ. This custom UIImagePickerController with over layer take picture only in specific region. 
http://www4.picturepush.com/photo/a/11522262/img/11522262.png

After take photo i will resize like FDJ.
http://www2.picturepush.com/photo/a/11522255/640/11522255.png

Can you help me please. i'm blocked!!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, it seems like you want to add a camera overlay view to your UIImagePickerController. See this [link for a tutorial](http://mworldapps.com/custom-camera-overlay-view-for-uiimagepickercontroller-how-to-block-pinch-zoom-2/) There are several other tutorials if you google for them. Implement the delegate `-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` . The info dictionary will contain the image:
`UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];` . You can then create a uiimageview and set the captured image. HTH.

Comment: The problem is the image taken is not in the specific region. With this solution we should resize image(because i don't know if it is iPhone 4 camera or iPhone 4s camera,...) and after scale image for the specific region.

Comment: Check this comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/9940119/1113598 Its worth a shot if it works for you.

Comment: As well as this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/10170518/1113598 where the user claims to have gotten it to work. And this for cropping http://stackoverflow.com/a/10119122/1113598.

Comment: I would have an image in specific region like my first image example.

Comment: Your image in a specific region is nothing but a resized camera layout. Did you give the links i posted above a try ?